# Does Vertx 3.9.0 supports Redis Json or not? Any other ways to achieve it?

Tags: java, redis, vert.x, redisjson, vertx-redis-client

I am working with Vertx 3.9.0, I am trying to get json data for a key from redis Server.

```
redisConnection.send(Request.cmd(Command.GET).arg(key), handler->{
  if(handler.succeeded()) {
    Response response = handler.result();
    System.out.println(response.toString());
    promise.complete();
  }else {
    System.out.println(handler.cause());
  }
});
```

I always get `WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value`

I am wondering whether Redis Json Support is provided by `vertx-redis-client:3.9.0` ?
If not then what are the alternatives to query Json data from Redis.

Comment: Redis doesn't support JSON as a type by default. Are you sure this is a JSON, and not a Hash? https://redis.io/topics/data-types

Comment: Yes I am using redisjson, you can have a look at https://oss.redislabs.com/redisjson/

Answer (score 0):

Vert.x Redis Client doesn't support Redis modules.

You can see all the supported commands here:
https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-redis-client/blob/master/src/main/java/io/vertx/redis/client/Command.java

Unfortunately, Vert.x Redis Client also doesn't support raw commands.

You can use [JRedisJSON](https://github.com/RedisJSON/JRedisJSON) for that, but you'll have to write a Vert.x wrapper yourself.